# Removing the difference between treatments

Tags: mathematical-statistics, biostatistics

Is there any statistical method to remove the difference between treatments observed before starting the treatments? I have measured the length of shoots on trees of three different treatments but unlucky they were different even before treatment onset!

Comment: There are several - you can use change scores, you can add starting length as a covariate, if you have lots of data about each shoot you can use propensity scores, you could try matching in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

If `start.len` has the starting length:

```
lm(y~x+start.len)
```

puts in starting length as a covariate (the order doesn't matter)
t
Note that you wrote of 'difference between treatments at the outset' when referring to different starting lengths. That's not a difference between treatments but a difference between the initial samples.